# Create ready event for custom plugin in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, plugins, dom-events, document-ready

I have created a plugin in pure JavaScript and wanted to make one event that will fire when my plugin is ready.

So that some other JavaScript code can subscribe to that event and act once the plugin is ready.

Currently I am following a simple approach as below.

```
var pluginLoadEvent = new CustomEvent(
  "plugin-ready",{
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
  }
);
```

And dispatch this event once the plugin is ready:

```
document.dispatchEvent(pluginLoadEvent);
```

The event is subscribed to like this:

```
document.addEventListener('plugin-ready',window.function_after_plugin_ready);
```

The issue is that my CustomEvent is being created and dispatched in a different file than subscriptions, which causes race condition problems where the event is dispatched before the subscriptions.

How can I ensure that the subscriptions happen before the dispatch?

Comment: Creating event in different function and dispatching that event in different function. It is not global I just rewrite code so that it can be understandable easily.This is for example.

Comment: Sorry for misleading Not relying on jquery and not global event. 
Just updated the code please check it now. :)

Comment: How is that plugin started? Is it some kind of a webcomponent a user can place directly into the HTML or does it need to be initiated inside JS (for example with `new Plugin( ... )`?

Comment: It is inside in JS.